# RAILS 4 - How to show NAME instead of ID in index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails newbie here.
I want my questions/view/index to show the name of the language associated with a question, rather than the language_id.

My question model is:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phrase, presence: true
  has_many :answers, dependent: :delete_all
  belongs_to :language
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :phrase
      t.string :language

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddLanguageIdToQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :questions, :language_id, :integer
  end
end
```

My language model is:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class CreateLanguages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :languages do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my questions controller:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.all
  @language = Language.find(@questions.language_id)
end
```

In the questions/_form.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :language_id %><br>
  <%= f.select :language_id, @languages.map { |l| [l.name, l.id] }, {:prompt => 'select language'} %>
</p>
```

And in the questions/view/index.html.erb:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>"<%= link_to question.phrase, question %>" in <%= question.language.name %>?%></li>
<% end %>
```

The error I keep getting, despite trying several variations of "question.language.name" (which works just fine in the show view) is "undefined method "language_id" in the index view.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Remove this line `@language = Language.find(@questions.language_id)` from the `index` action.It is wrong and useless.

Comment: And also you have to include the `association` in your `Language` model.If it is `one-to-many` then `has_many :questions` or if it is `one-to-one` then `has_one :question`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your index action to:

```
def index
  @questions = Question.all.includes(:language)
end
```

**edit**

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <% unless question.language.nil? %>
    <li>"<%= link_to question.phrase, question %>" in <%= question.language.name %>?%></li>  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OR

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>"<%= link_to question.phrase, question %>" in <%= question.language.name unless question.language.nil? %>?%></li>
<% end %>
```

Both will work fine depends on you what do you want.

feel free to ask if problem continues or not solved.

**Your Problem**

What you were doing wrong was:

finding all questions and then this line was wrong finding all question's language at once.

```
  @language = Language.find(@questions.language_id)
```

And to avoid this: better solution is to avoid N + 1 query problem using `includes`

Comment: I've delete my answer. please explain your solution so the OP understands what is the issue. I did not read your answer properly.

Comment: My bad, I thought u have only addressed the n+1 issue

Comment: When I try this solution, I get an undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass error, referring to the question.language.name in index.html.erb.

Comment: That did it! Does it mean the problem was being caused by some questions in the database which were entered early on in the development process without associated languages being recorded? (even though the presence of the associated language is validated now?)

Comment: yes. there were two reasons. first was in your controller as mentioned and second you mentioned in comment

Answer (score 1):

[**ActiveRecord Associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

This sounds like a job for ActiveRecord Associations, specifically [the `has_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

ActiveRecord associations basically use a [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your database to pull relational data & append to your object. Currently, you're only focused on using a single object, without any associated data.

--

Your problem can be fixed using the following:

```
#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :language
end

#app/models/language.rb
Class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :questions
end
```

This will allow you to call the following in your controller & view:

```
#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
Class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @questions = Question.all
   end
end

#app/views/questions/index.html.erb
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= question.language.name %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Bonus**

You can use the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method to provide you with the ability to stop the [`law of dementer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) issue:

```
#app/models/question.rb
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :language
   delegate :name, to: :language, prefix: true #-> @question.language_name
end
```

Comment: There is an n:1 association between questions and languages (a question has exactly one language, but a language may belong to many questions). In your answer this is reversed and I think this is not what bkong28 wanted.

Comment: Sven is right - a question has 1 language but a language may belong to many questions.

Comment: Updated to reflect this!

Answer (score 0):

`@questions.language_id` is incorrect because you are trying to retrieve a single id from an array. i.e. `Question.all` returns an array. Also, `Language.find` requires a single id parameter to return a single language.

What exactly are you trying to return with `Language.find(@questions.language_id)` ? An array of languages that have a question that belong to it?

Also, where is the _form.html.erb partial called? By default, rails scaffold will call the partial in the new and edit actions and therefore if you are trying to set `@languages` for the select field in the form partial, then you would not do it in the index action. Also, Consider using a [collection select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for this field as it is for an association.

Comment: I'm trying to find (and show in the index) the language that was selected in the form when the question was created. There's no problem getting the language_id to show, but I want it to show the language instead. The form partial is called in 'edit' and 'new' views. I considered using 'collection_select', but went with the simpler 'select' as I thought the former would be overkill.

Comment: In that case you don't need to have to set '@language' in the controller. When you loop through each question in the view just make the question.language.name conditional if question has language. i.e @G.B's answer is correct only I would have if question.language.present? instead of unless question.language.nil?